# Proving that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{n^{2}}$ converges.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have tried out a bunch of tests but I cannot seem to find one that will prove its convergence. How would I go about proving that it converges using the standard convergence tests?

Comparison test:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{n^{2}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{n^{2}} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^{2}\cdot(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})}$

Which I then compared to the p-series $\frac{1}{n^{2}}$.

Then $\frac{1}{n^{2}} < \frac{1}{n^{2}\cdot(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})}$

But here $\frac{1}{n^{2}}$ is convergent because p=2 and this doesn't really help me to establish the right side as being convergent.

Comment: What tests did you try? Can you show some working?

Comment: You can use the comparison test.

Comment: I tried using the comparison test along with a p-series (1/n^2) test. I also tried the limit comparison test and ratio test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that $$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}{n^2}=\frac{\sqrt{1+1/n}+1}{n^{3/2}}<\frac{3}{n^{3/2}}.$$ Now use the comparison test.

Answer (score 1):

The intuition is the following: the numerator is (a sum of) square root, the denominator is a square, then the quotient is something that should behave as $n^{-3/2}$, $$\frac{\text{numerator}}{\text{denominator}}\sim \frac{\sqrt n}{n^2} \sim \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}.$$ Hence it is reasonable to believe that the series converges. To make this precise let's apply the comparison test: $$\frac{\sqrt{n + 1} + \sqrt{n}}{n^2} \le \frac{2\sqrt{n + 1}}{n^2} \le \frac{2\sqrt{2n}}{n^2} = 2\sqrt{\frac{2n}{n^4}} = \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{n^{3/2}}.$$ This proves the result.